# How is this loop crashing my program?

Tags: c++, gcc

I can't seem to figure out why my program is crashing. When I remove the while loop under  "//Displays name options" The program runs fine. The code compiles on GCC  with no warnings. Could it be my compiler? Does it have something to do with fstream? Help would be appreciated.

Oh yea. If your wondering this program will read data.txt and Load the appropriate data to an instance of the player function. It is in a incomplete state at the moment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#define cls system("cls");

bool Pload = false;

void menu();

struct player {
    int Px, Py, life = 20;
    string name = "";
};

main() {
    menu();
}

void menu() {
    string cLine,names,input;

    int x,i,lineNum = 0;
    fstream data;

    menu:

    data.open("data.txt");
    //Gets list of all names in data.txt, Adds them to string names
    while(data.good()) {
        getline(data,cLine);
    if(cLine[0] == '/') {
        names += cLine;
    }
}           
names += '\n';

//Displays name options
cls
cout << "Welcome to  W A L K.\n\nWhat is your name?\n";
while(names[i] != '\n') 
{
    cout << i; 
    if(names[i] == '/') {cout << endl;i++;} else {cout << names[i];i++;}
}
cout << endl;
getline(cin,input);

//checks if name exits and loads file data into player/world objects 
data.close();
data.open("data.txt");
while(data.good()) {
    lineNum++;
    getline(data,cLine);
    if(cLine.erase(0,1) == input) {
        cls cout << "Found Name" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);

        }

    }
//Restarts menu
data.close();
goto menu;
}
```

data.txt

```
/Sammy
x:0
y:0
l:20
\

/Mary
x:7
y:9
l:20
\


/Dill
x:7
y:9
l:20
\

/Jack
x:7
y:9
l:20
\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your debugger would've uncovered this, or simply using some `cout` statements.

When you declare `i` in the following manner:

```
int x,i,lineNum = 0;
```

You declare 3 `int` and initialise `lineNum` to `0`; however the other two remain unitialised, and therefore it's undefined behaviour to use them.

```
while(names[i] != '\n') // UB, i is unitialised
```

Prefer to declare and initialise one variable per line, like so:

```
auto x = 0;
auto i = 0;
auto lineNum = 0;
```

The use of `auto` also forces you to initialise them to a value.

If you wanted to write it all on one line, you'd have to write

```
auto x = 0, i = 0, lineNum = 0;
```

But it's just not as readable and no one will thank you for it.

Comment: Wow that really helped. I would up vote but this is one of my first questions. Thank you.